# Could it be a structure of "How many -singular noun- is there?"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, plural-forms, singular

We had an argument in our collage if it's possible to have such structure:

> "How many -**singular noun**- is there?"

For example:

> How many **chair is** there?

**The claim of the supporters**: This structure should be used in case that t is not known whether there is one one or more chairs there. While *just* in case that it is known certainty that there are more than one chair, it should be "how many chairs are there".

**The claim of the opponents**: This structure cannot be since using the phrase "how many" always should be with a plural noun.

Both sides are not native English speakers, then I would like to know what is the truth.

Comment: You cannot have **how many {singular noun}**

Comment: No, the form *How many [singular noun] is there?* is never valid. The nearest context I can think of where it *might* be possible to do something like this is [*(if) there is/are more than one*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35389/), as explored on that ELU question.

Answer (score 5):

> How many chair is there?

This is not grammatically correct in English. "How many" refers to an unknown number, "many" refers to more than one.; "How many?" requires a plural verb.
 The correct question is:

> How many chairs **are** there?

And

> What is the number of chairs

Asks the same question without the need for "many" and the need for a plural verb. "Number" is singular, grammatically.

The answer to "what number" can be from zero to infinity. (0 to ∞), or any negative number.